# Ad Hoc Distribution for iPad

Tags: ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm a newborn developer for iPad, I finally finished an app and I want to simulate the Ad hoc Distribution, although I have read many Q&A and a book I still can't do it. I don't know how to build and release, and then how to zip the project. I can't access the Dev Center because Apple hasn't recognized my companies identity, so I don't have the certifications, is this the problem? If so, what can I do?

Please be patient with me, I really want to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't build for devices without a Dev Center account.